# Get a value out of a multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have this array below and need to know the var to get the serialized string in `["option_value"]`.  My limited understanding leads me to believe it would be `$resdata[0]['option_value']` but that returns `NULL`.

```
$resdata =

    array(1) { [0]=> array(5) { ["option_id"]=> string(3) "853" ["blog_id"]=> string(1) "0" ["option_name"]=> string(24) "wp_table_reloaded_data_2" ["option_value"]=> string(1125) "a:9:{s:2:"id";i:2;s:11:"category_id";s:1:"2";s:4:"name";s:20:"Copy of Test Table 1";s:11:"description";s:27:"
    This is a test table

    ";s:10:"visibility";a:2:{s:4:"rows";a:2:{i:0;b:0;i:1;b:0;}s:7:"columns";a:3:{i:0;b:0;i:1;b:0;i:2;b:0;}}s:4:"data";a:2:{i:0;a:3:{i:0;s:14:"
    test 1a

    ";i:1;s:19:"
    test 1b blah

    ";i:2;s:14:"
    test 1c

    ";}i:1;a:3:{i:0;s:14:"
    test 2a

    ";i:1;s:14:"
    test 2b

    ";i:2;s:14:"
    test 2c

    ";}}s:7:"options";a:19:{s:22:"alternating_row_colors";b:1;s:19:"print_name_position";s:5:"above";s:26:"print_description_position";s:5:"below";s:18:"cache_table_output";b:1;s:16:"custom_css_class";s:0:"";s:15:"use_tablesorter";b:1;s:15:"datatables_sort";b:1;s:19:"datatables_paginate";b:1;s:27:"datatables_paginate_entries";i:10;s:23:"datatables_lengthchange";b:1;s:17:"datatables_filter";b:1;s:15:"datatables_info";b:1;s:25:"datatables_customcommands";s:0:"";s:9:"row_hover";b:0;s:12:"first_row_th";b:0;s:12:"table_footer";b:0;s:10:"print_name";b:0;s:17:"print_description";b:0;s:21:"datatables_tabletools";b:0;}s:13:"last_modified";s:19:"2011-07-01 23:21:31";s:14:"last_editor_id";s:1:"6";}" ["autoload"]=> string(3) "yes" } }
```

Comment: please post the result of the following: `var_export($resdata);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have should be working.  How are you trying to use it?  Are you trying to echo or print it?

```
foreach($resdata as $v){
  echo $v['option_value']
}
```